# Android delete method don't work cause: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time

Tags: android, android-room, crud

I try to develop an Android app ( insert, update, get, delete ). But my delete function doesn't work. ( insert, update and get work verry well)

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mounangabouka.intimes, PID: 32040
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:385)
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:469)
at com.mounangabouka.intimes.dao.ArticleDao_Impl.delete(ArticleDao_Impl.java:145)
at com.mounangabouka.intimes.database.ArticleRepository.deleteArticle(ArticleRepository.java:44)
at com.mounangabouka.intimes.viewmodel.ArticleViewModel.suppArticle(ArticleViewModel.java:33)
at com.mounangabouka.intimes.viewmodel.GetActivity$3.onClick(GetActivity.java:124)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7352)
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14230)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7318)
at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27800)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)

My Dao:

```
@Delete
    void delete(Article article);
My Repository

 public void deleteArticleAll( ) {

        mArticleDao.deleteAll();
    }
```

My viewModel

```
public void deleteArticle(Article article) { mRepository.deleteArticle(article); }
```

on my activity

```
 private void onClickOnBtnDelete(Article article) {

        btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent del = new Intent(GetActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                articleViewModel.deleteArticle(article);
                startActivity(del);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have your viewmodel do the work on a background thread. You presumably already have code for doing inserts and updates on background threads; use the same thing for your delete operations.

Comment: I use the same thing but it do not work, I don't know why

Comment: thank you . I solved it by adding AppDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> mUserDao.delete(user));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform operations on the background as the stack says , since you are coding your application in java  , kotlin coroutines are not useful to you . If you want you can interop . Solution in java  is as follows :

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       //Perform your Room database operations
    }
});
```

Comment: Comment if you face any issues

Answer (score 0):

Use Coroutines:

```
MainScope().launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
articleViewModel.deleteArticle(article)
}
```